# If background is changed rotate logo

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that when you *scroll change's the background color*.I need to add `logo rotation` when is `background color` is `white`.

I did it and everything work but little bit a problem that logo rotation work's **slowly (not properly)** sometimes didn't work when you scroll fast.I need to realize that when is background color is white `rotate` the logo at once.And else return to default position.

`if($body.css('background-color') === "rgb(245, 245, 245)")`

Here's my main if condition which **check if bg is white or not**

Please help.

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/DuudeXX8/pen/EpQPLK?editors=1010) link

Full js code

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    // selectors
    let $window = $(window),
      $body = $('body'),
      $panel = $('.panel'),
     $header = $("#header");
    //
    let scroll = $window.scrollTop() + ($window.height() / 3);

    $panel.each(function() {
      let $this = $(this);

      if ($this.position().top <= scroll && $this.position().top + $this.height() > scroll) {

        // taking bg color
        $body.css('background-color', `#${$(this).data('color')}`);
        $header.css('background-color', `#${$(this).data('color')}`);
      }
    });

    if($body.css('background-color') !== "rgb(245, 245, 245)"){
      TweenMax.to(".card-logo",0.3, {rotationY:180})
    } else {
      TweenMax.to(".card-logo",0.3, {rotationY:0})
    }


  }).scroll();
```

Comment: your background has a transition time before being white, so the animation doesn't launch because the background is not white yet

Comment: does TweenMax have a callback/promise when it is done?

Comment: @epascarello yup this method is  __onComplete:(here your'e function)__

Comment: so set it there....?

Comment: @epascarello dont need for this

Comment: Where is white being set? Is it in the forEach or is it default?

Comment: @epascarello in the data-color look at html file please.Js get data attribute in html and change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved.

All I need to be that wrap all in any html tag and it work's.

And check if it color changed then rotate the logo

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/DuudeXX8/pen/JaRadM?editors=1010)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    // selectors
    let $window = $(window),
      $body = $('body'),
      $panel = $('.panel'),
      $header = $("#header"),
      $foo = $('.foo')
    //
    let scroll = $window.scrollTop() + ($window.height() / 3);

    $panel.each(function() {
      let $this = $(this);

      if ($this.position().top <= scroll && $this.position().top + $this.height() > scroll) {

        // taking bg color
        $foo.css('background-color', `#${$(this).data('color')}`);
        $header.css('background-color', `#${$(this).data('color')}`);
      }
    });

    if($foo.css('background-color') !== "rgb(245, 245, 245)"){
      TweenMax.to(".card-logo",0.3, {rotationY:180})
    } else {
      TweenMax.to(".card-logo",0.3, {rotationY:0})
    }


  }).scroll();
```